# Integral of diffeomorphism

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I'm studying differential geometry, and there is this passage I don't understand: we have a diffeomorphism f of $R^k$ such that $f(0)=0$. Then he says that $f(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{d}{ds} f(xs) ds $ and I still understand (he's just using fundamental theorem of calculus right?). But then what I don't understand is $f(x)=\sum_{1}^{k}x_ig_i(x)$, where $g_i(x)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}f(xs) ds $. I really don't understand why. I even tried with an example in $R^2$ but I assume I didn't even understand the notation. Can you explain this? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To a function be an diffeomorphism it needs to be of the form $f\colon U\subset\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}^k$, where $U$ is an open set, because it's derivate is an isomorphism. Also, fixing $x\in\mathbb{R}^k$, we can call $f(t\cdot x) = f\circ r(t)$, where $r\colon t\in[0,1]\mapsto t\cdot x$ and by the chain rule
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}f(tx) &=(f\circ r)'(t)\\
&= f'(r(t))\cdot r'(t)\\
&= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(t x) & \cdots & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(t x)
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
(x_1,\dots,x_k)\\
&= x_1\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(t x) + \cdots +x_k\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(t x).
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}f(tx)dt \\
&= \int_0^1 x_1\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(t x) + \cdots +x_k\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(t x)dt\\
&=\sum_{i = 1}^k x_i\int_0^1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(t x)dt\\
&=\sum_{i = 1}^k x_ig_i(x).
\end{align}